# What is the metric of Vaidya black-hole horizon?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

The metric of a Vaidya black hole in outgoing/retarted null coordinates are
$$ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2m(u)}{r^2}\right)du^2-2dudr+r^2\Big(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 \Big)$$
The eveolving horizon locates at $r=2m(u)$ and thus $dr=2\dot{m}du$ with dot denoting $\frac{d}{du}$. Hence, I conclude that the degenerate metric of the Vaidya black-hole horizon should be 
$$ds^2=-4\dot{m}du^2+4m(u)^2\Big(d\theta^2+\sin^2\theta d\phi^2 \Big)$$

Am I right? Thank you very much!

I am unsure because the null time coordinate $u$ is NOT orthogonal to $r$.

Comment: Do you have a reason to believe you are wrong?

Comment: @ACuriousMind I guess I am right, but not sure.

Comment: What do you mean by "the degenerate metric?" Are you talking about a metric whose signature has a zero in it?

Comment: ...or the induced metric on the surface $r=2m$?

Comment: Hello @Ben Crowell and Kris White! I have re-edited the title to avoid ambiguity. By  "the degenerate metric", I mean the horizon is only 2+1 dimensional, instead of 3+1 dimensional like the full spacetime.

Comment: Just a comment to notice that the horizon you're talking about isn't the "event horizon" of the Vaidya spacetime.  $r = 2m(u)$ is the "apparent horizon", which moves faster than light (it's a *spacelike* hypersurface).  The "event horizon" is harder to define in this case, but can easily be seen with a plot of the null geodesics, using $t = u + r$ versus $r$.